# Flask-Security reset password

Tags: flask, flask-security

I'm trying to use Flask-Security on a project. I've made may search on SO but I just can't find a way to simply implement a the reset password functionality. I just don't understand how to use the flask-security APi in this case.

I notice that all the template can be found on their github, I also check the source code but it's like a mystery.

If you have some good tips, advice or example on how to implement reset password it would be really kind.

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn on Flask-Security's [`SECURITY_RECOVERABLE` setting](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/configuration.html#feature-flags). How exactly you do that depends on your code, but it's something along the lines of

```
app.config['SECURITY_RECOVERABLE'] = True
```

This will [turn on a link to the password reset page](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/8b1ab24341b0b4cd008ab19c76717fd8b482e81f/flask_security/templates/security/_menu.html#L8-L10).

Comment: Thanks dirn, I'll look at it. sry for late reply.